# How does ASP.NET HttpServerUtility.Transfer break the control flow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, control-flow

By "how does" I mean "by what mechanism" not "to what effect".  Control doesn't return to the calling method after you call [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer%28VS.71%29.aspx)("...");.  At the language runtime level, how does this happen? Does it throw an exception or trigger something that aborts the thread?  I'm just curious.  What are other examples of this pattern (calling a method to terminate execution)?

Comment: The answer is in the documentation you already linked.

Comment: The linked document says that it terminates the execution, but it doesn't say how, which was my question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It eventually calls `End` which throws a `ThreadAbortException` that terminates the current thread of execution.  See the documentation here

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx